# Creating a subdomain with dot(.) symbol

Tags: dns, cpanel

Can we create a subdomain on our web server without the dot symbol?

For e.g I have domain name www.example.com. Now if I want to create a subdomain www.myexample.com. Is it possible?

Recently, we have option to create subdomain with dot symbol only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are denoted by the dot.

www.mydomain.com would not be a subdomain of www.domain.com -- in both those cases, "www" is the subdomain. "mydomain.com" and "domain.com" are just different domains.

Comment: Thank you.
But I got a query. http://jobpac.com.au/ and http://myjobpac.com.au/ are on same server. 
which share same backend? Any idea on hot to do that?

Comment: Might also be worth noting, you can set up a second domain such as "mydomain.com" and then set up its DNS records so that "www.mydomain.com" does a CNAME redirection to bounce users over to "www.domain.com". More on CNAME records here: https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/cname

Comment: If you want to have both domains go to the same system you can use CNAME DNS references as suggested in my last comment. However, when users go to myjobpac.com.au the address bar in their browser will change to jobpac.com.au. If you want the domain to stay the same in the address bar then you'll have to set up the web server to use Virtual Hosts, and point both Virtual Hosts to the same directory on the server. More info on Virtual Hosts here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Answer (score 0):

No. [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) defines an HTTP URL as follows:

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
> ```
>
> where `<host>` and `<port>` are as described in Section 3.1. If :`<port>` is omitted, the port defaults to `80`.

Section 3.1 defines the `<host>` part as follows:

> The fully qualified domain name of a network host, or its IP address as a set of four decimal digit groups separated by ".". Fully qualified domain names take the form as described in Section 3.5 of RFC 1034 and Section 2.1 of RFC 1123: **a sequence of domain labels separated by "."**, each domain label starting and ending with an alphanumerical character and possibly also containing "-" characters. The rightmost domain label will never start with a digit, though, which syntactically distinguishes all domain names from the IP addresses.

Sub-domains work from [right to left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain):

> for example, `wikipedia.org` comprises a subdomain of the `org` domain, and `en.wikipedia.org` comprises a subdomain of the domain `wikipedia.org`

`www.example.com` and `www.myexample.com` are considered to be two *separate* subdomains of `com`, because their second-from-right "domain label" (`myexample` vs `example`) differs; neither is considered to be a sub-domain of the other.